# Java list of java.util.function

Tags: java

Is it possible to create a list of functions in Java?

I have a bunch of functions, without parameter nor return type, and would like to put them in a list. I tried with `List<Consumer<Void>>` but can't seem to get them in there.

Comment: Functions with no parameter and no return type? So they are not `java.util.Function`. In fact, why do you call them "functions"?

Comment: Why not encapsulate them in a `Runnable` if their return type is `void` and has no parameters?

Comment: Aha, brilliant, didn't know about Runnable. That works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these "functions" are `void` methods without parameters, you can use `Runnable`:

```
class MyClass {
    void someMethod() { ... }
    static void anotherMethod() { ... }
}

MyClass obj = new MyClass();

List<Runnable> list = new ArrayList<>();

// for instance methods
list.add(obj::someMethod);

// for static methods
list.add(MyClass::anotherMethod);
```

This works because `Runnable` is a [functional interface](http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/08/java-8-functional-interfaces.html) and its `run()` method matches your methods: `void` and no arguments.